# Where can I find the number of vertices, edges, and faces in my scene in Blender 2.8?

Tags: scene

In Blender 2.79b, you could see the number of vertices, edges, and faces in your scene on the bar at the top. Is there a way you can access this information in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bottom right corner in the status bar.

Comment: +1.. i have a big @ss thunderbolt display... need to look around more before throwing my hands up in the air and searching on SE..

Answer (score 9):

My stats were missing from my status bar somehow and I had to right-click the status bar to bring up the option to display the info I wanted to see

Comment: That's Blender 2.9x isn't it?

Comment: Correct, 2.9x. I thought I'd add it seeing how this thread came up when I searched for the issue and it's nice when old issues have updates.